# Write Bytes from Textbox in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save text from a textbox as bytes. For example, The text from Textbox1 is "00001E0403" and I want to save them as bytes. What do I do then?

Comment: First you read [ask] then take the [tour] then do some research on your problem, then try to implement what you learned, *then* you post a question which shows the effort spent trying to solve your problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Save them where, exactly? To a spreadsheet cell, a database field, a variable in memory, a file on disk? And what specifically do you mean by *as bytes*? They're already bytes. Everything in your computer's memory is in bytes.

Comment: Well, I want to save the text to a file. But the problem is, this is gonna save as text, not bytes. I don't want the text to be 00001E0403, I want the hex values to be 00001E0403.

Comment: Otherwise, how do I convert TextBox1's data into text instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can save as an array of bytes. Trying using this command:

```
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textbox1.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Imports System.Globalization
Private Sub GetBytes()
    Dim l As Integer = TextBox1.Text.Length - 1
    Dim dataIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim data(l \ 2) As Byte
    For i As Integer = 0 To l Step 2
        Dim hexChars As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, Math.Min(2, TextBox1.Text.Length - i))
        Dim dataByte As Byte
        Byte.TryParse(hexChars, NumberStyles.HexNumber, Nothing, dataByte)
        data(dataIndex) = dataByte
        dataIndex += 1
    Next i
End Sub
```